# Modifying Image View Dynamically on a button click inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
package com.example.layout.layout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MovieInfoFile extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OPTION="argument_option";
    HashMap[]items=new HashMap[30];
    int i;
    public ImageView image;
    TextView name;
    TextView des;
    TextView stars;
    TextView year;
    TextView rating;
    public static MovieInfoFile newInstance(int option)
    {
        MovieInfoFile fragment=new MovieInfoFile();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();

        args.putInt(ARG_OPTION,option);
        fragment.setArguments(args);



        return fragment;

    }

    public MovieInfoFile() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.movieinfolayout, container, false);
        Button loadnext=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
         image=(ImageView) view.findViewById((R.id.image1));
         name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameans);
         des=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desans);
         stars=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.starans);
         year=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yearans);
         rating=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingans);
         enter code hereView.OnClickListener aButtonChangeImageListener=new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId()==R.id.next)
                {

                    int id=(Integer)items[1].get("image");
                    image.setImageResource(id);
                }



            }
        };





        return view;
    }
}



Here is the layout (XML file)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/baground"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="315dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_weight="0.53" />
     <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:id="@+id/table1">
         <TableRow>
             <TextView
                 android:text="Movie Name: "
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/name"

                 />
             <TextView
                 android:text="Movie Name: "
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/nameans"

                 />
             </TableRow>
         <TableRow>
             <TextView
                 android:text="Description: "
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/des"

                 />
             <TextView
                 android:text="Description: "
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/desans"

                 />
         </TableRow>
         <TableRow>
             <TextView
                 android:text="Stars "
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/star"

                 />
             <TextView
                 android:text="Stars "
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/starans"

                 />
         </TableRow>
         <TableRow>
             <TextView
                 android:text="Year"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/year"


                 />
             <TextView
                 android:text="Year"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/yearans"

                 />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow>
             <TextView
                 android:text="Rating"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/rating"

                 />
             <TextView
                 android:text="Rating"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:id="@+id/ratingans"

                 />
         </TableRow>


     </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LoadPrev"
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loadnext"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/next"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to change the image view dynamically on a button click inside a fragment. But when i do this, it is giving me error, "Unfortunately your app has stopped".Can any one help me in this and tell me the right way of modifying views dynamically on a button click with in a fragment.

Comment: please post the stack trace from when this happens

Answer (score 1):

for the **button load next**(i guess after clicking this image should change), So pass **aButtonChangeImageListener** to the Button loadNext like this:

```
loadNext.setOnClickListener(aButtonChangeImageListener);
```

before return view line